# View reference image in Wireframe and solid view

Tags: modeling, wireframe

I am modeling using a reference image. The image is behind the model and I need to see through the model, i.e. have the model in wireframe but the image in solid. Is that possible? I am using mac and Blender 2.9.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways (or more?) to do it.

*Use empty images*

Add an empty image, it will be rendered as image even in wireframe mode.

[image]

*Use image as plane*

But in preview or rendered mode, limit the viewport display of your model to wireframe:

[image]

Comment: Thanks lemon :-)